# Jquery: How do I fire/play a sound file when I want?

Tags: jquery, playback, audio

I have some code that basically inflates a 'balloon' through 15 or so stages and then makes it pop at the 16th stage. (yes, images are changed). What I'm wondering now is if it's possible to use Jquery to play a sound file whenever I reach that 16th stage (or when whatever var reaches whatever value) - in other words...when I want.

I've found several jquery sound plugins but they all create this player which I must then click for it to play the file. How do I skip that 'click' part so that the sound is just...directly/automatically played?

http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/

All help is appreciated
G.Campos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrmm...seems like no one bothered to check here :o

The answer to my question turned out to be simple:

1.- Loading the player:

```
// load mp3 player with autoplay on
$(".mp3").jmp3();
```

2.- Modifying jsmp3.js where it reads:

```
"autoplay": "false" ---> change it to "true"
```

The rest was just hiding the player.

Oh well, congrats to...myself

Comment: How could we trigger the ring tone or vibration on mobile with jquery?

I like to warn the user when certain data arrived, while they are still idle on the web page?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to pull that off as I've avoided cellphones for as long as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

seems like directly using HTML embed would work just as well

Comment: this was before i even knew of html5 - not sure if html5 was out by then